# How to input numbers in python with comma separators?

Tags: python

I seem to remember that there is a syntax in python to directly input numbers with comma separators (`1,000,000` instead of `1000000`). Googling the issue gives either results on how to:

1. Print numbers with comma separators

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US')
locale.format("%d", 1255000, grouping=True)
```

2. Remove commas from numbers to input into python

```
a = '1,000,000'
int(a.replace(',' , ''))
```

I don't want to do either and the plethora of results stops me from finding the information I need.

Comment: Instead of commas, Python allows the use of underscores. For example 1_000_000. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/

Comment: That's what I was looking for. If you submit it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of commas, Python allows the use of underscores.

See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/

> ## grouping decimal numbers by thousands
>
> amount = 10_000_000.0
>
> ## grouping hexadecimal addresses by words
>
> addr = 0xCAFE_F00D
>
> ## grouping bits into nibbles in a binary literal
>
> flags = 0b_0011_1111_0100_1110
>
> ## same, for string conversions
>
> flags = int('0b_1111_0000', 2)